# Another term for 'feature / featured / article / write up' for a brand

Tags: single-word-requests, brands

I am currently working on a website that will allow users to sign up and create their own product features.

In this context, a product feature is a write up with pictures and information about a single product. This website will also allow people to do write ups on events coverage too.

Ideally, I wanted to have either of the following:

```
www.featured.com
www.ftrd.com
```

But of course they are unavailable, I am now looking for another way to describe this sort of website and looking for a simple wording as its going to be used for the brand too.

I have looked for similiar words and it returned write up, article, post etc but none of these have the same feeling as 'featured' as it gives a higher level to the article.

I am happy to use modern terms such as dropping the vowels, or ending in ly etc.

Comment: Does it include product reviews too?

Comment: Going with the slang adding *ly*, maybe try "featurely".

Comment: sounds like an advertorial? or just a "plug". What about www.plugged.com